# Python: How to convert image alpha channel to grayscale?

Tags: python

I used machine learning to cut out a portrait, but the result was a portrait, not a grayscale map, how do I convert it to a grayscale map? I want background is black and portrait is white
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use skimage library to simply convert RGB to GrayScale image.

```
from skimage import color 
from skimage import io


origImage = io.imread('your_image_path')

gsImage = color.rgb2gray(origImage)
```